# A special review?

Tags: discussion, review

Must be something special - 7 close votes are not enough?

https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/255605

[image]

Comment: I think it's just because we aren't all 3k+ rep

Comment: That means that we need to delete it also :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at each of those users you'll notice that 3 of them have less than 3,000 reputation. They can't vote to close.

When you have less than 3k reputation the "Close" button in the LQP queue reads "Recommend closure" and flags a post for closure with the specific reason they chose.

This is similar with the "delete" button. Once you get 20k it will change from "Recommend deletion" to just "Delete" (providing the answer meets the criteria for 20k user deletion).

Comment: That was one of the not so obvious transitions for me - and now I know what becomes of my "recommend deletion" votes :-)

Comment: @guntbert Actually, 6 recommend deletion votes *will* delete a post. Dunno why 3 recommend closures and 4 closes won't close it..

Comment: That could be a bug..., shall I add the tag?

Comment: @Seth I think because this way, it's confusing for less people. Who should the system show when the question gets closed? Should it show all 7 people, or just the ones with >3k rep? IMO, both solutions would be confusing for people that don't know how reviews work.

Comment: @Dan This is the low quality post queue, so all the reviews should be shown IMO.

Comment: @guntbert I doubt it, but you might ask on MSE.

Comment: @guntbert checking it out in Su, is a flag "vote to close". The users are just pilling up flags over the post so it gets pushed through the close queue.

Comment: Yup, what @Braiam said. A "recommend closure" review just results in a recommend closure flag; no vote or anything.